# generate function name yielding a specific function selector

Tags: solidity, keccak, function-selector

Suppose I have a function with arguments `(address _to, uint256 number)`
The function selector is found using

```
let signature = "name(address,uint256)";
let selector = Keccack256(signature) ;
```

I want to find a name for my function that will generate a specific selector
say for example, 0x19284901. How would I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retro engineer the byte selectors, those are made from the keccack256 hashing as you shown it.

Though, you can use 4 bytes selectors database that are free to use, here is the example of one: https://www.4byte.directory/docs/

If you cannot find the selector that you need, you can brute force (creating a random function name, until getting the correct function selector)

Comment: How would you do that

Comment: The function selector that you need is not in the db ?

Comment: No I really need to generate an arbitrary function selector from the arguements

Comment: So you can run a loop until you find the correct 4 bytes selector.
For this, just alter the function name until that the condition is met, e.g.

```
let selector
while selector !== "0x19284901" {
    const random_name = some_random_name();
    const full_name = random_name + "(address,uint256)";
    const selector = keccak256(full_name);
}

print(selector);
```

Please note that it's pseudo-code, for you to understand easily.